# Nested PCA : is it the same to reduce dimension one time by m and to reduce m times by 1?

Tags: pca

My data is initially represented in a vector space $E$ of dimension $n$.

I want to reduce the dimension by $m$, so I apply a PCA process to obtain a vector space $E'$ of dimension $n-m$.

If I had applied PCA $m$ times but reducing the dimension only by $1$, I would have obtained another vector space $E''$ of dimension $n-m$.

**Question** : is $E'$ the same vector space as $E''$ ?
I would say no, because in the second case, when reducing the dimension at the $i^{th}$ step, the covariance matrix is estimated using data that has already been distorded by the previous steps... Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the result should be the same (aside from any computation round-off error). Go ahead and try it!

PCA is simply a singular-value decomposition on the centered data matrix, **X**.

Thus, it amounts to an additive representation of orthogonal components:

$$\textbf{X} = \textbf{U}\textbf{D}\textbf{V}^T = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i\textbf{u}_i\textbf{v}_i^T$$

Where $\textbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $\{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_p\}$
and $\textbf{u}_i$ are the left singular vectors (columns of $\textbf{U}$) and $\textbf{v}_i^T$ are the right singular vectors (rows of $\textbf{V}$).

Therefore, the n-m dimensional representation truncates this sum after n-m terms.
The n-1 representation truncates this sum after n-1 terms. By taking away the last term in the sum, you've reduced the dimensions by 1. If you were to compute another SVD on the resulting matrix, you'd end up with the same exact terms in the summation.

(Of course when trying this out, you have to keep in mind that singular vectors (and thus PCs and scores) are unique up to a sign (+/-) *(in most practical cases, that is - when geometric multiplicity of all eigenvalues is 1, if people want to get pedantic - otherwise they are not unique at all)*

So try this out on the iris data in R:

x=princomp(iris[,1:4])

y=princomp(x$scores[,1:3])

round(abs(x$scores[,1:2])-abs(y$scores[,1:2]),13)==0

Take the absolute value because the sign of second PC of y is actually opposite the 
 second PC of x. Round the difference between the values to 13 decimal places because, 
 like I said, roundoff error bound to be an issue. Then test that there is no difference.

Comp.1 Comp.2
  [1,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [2,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [3,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [4,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [5,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [6,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [7,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [8,]   TRUE   TRUE
  [9,]   TRUE   TRUE
 [10,]   TRUE   TRUE
 [11,]   TRUE   TRUE
 [12,]   TRUE   TRUE
 [13,]   TRUE   TRUE
 [14,]   TRUE   TRUE
 [15,]   TRUE   TRUE

ETC.